# What happens when a file on a remote disk is not reachable while inserting records?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have `database` with two **`filegroups`** **`A`** and **`B`**. **`filegroup B`** contains a single file on a remote server.

What will happen when I am inserting records in a **`table`** defined on **`filegroup B`**, while the remote server is offline?

Will the database engine store everything in RAM until the remote server is available again? Will it timeout? Will it write to a temporary file on the local disk?

Just to be clear: the database engine is running local, but the table is stored on a remote server.

Comment: Having a database file on a remote location seems like a very bad idea. There's so many reasons your database could end up in recovery mode as a result.

Comment: why is it a bad idea? sql server installation on fileshare with smb is supported: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-with-smb-fileshare-as-a-storage-option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table will be "accessible" for any operations that do not involve access to the file storage. You could test that easily by creating a secondary filegroup on a usb drive and performing actions when the usb drive is disconnected.

```
use [master]
go

create database [mysplitdb] on primary 
(name = N'FileA', filename = N'C:\SQLData\mysplitdbA.mdf'),
filegroup B
(name = 'FileB', filename = 'E:\FileB.ndf') --<-- file on usb drive
log on 
(name = N'mysplitdb_log', filename = N'C:\SQLData\mysplitdb_log.LDF')
go

use [mysplitdb]
go

create table dbo.OnSecFileGroup
(
    id int identity primary key clustered,
    col1 int,
    col2 varchar(100)
) on [B];


insert into dbo.OnSecFileGroup(col1, col2)
select top (10000) row_number() over(order by (select null)), a.name
from master.dbo.spt_values as a
cross join master.dbo.spt_values as b;

checkpoint;

select *
from dbo.OnSecFileGroup;

--remove the usb drive(abruptly)

--works, from cache
select top 500 *
from dbo.OnSecFileGroup
where id between 5000 and 6000

--works
select top 500 *
from dbo.OnSecFileGroup
where id > 9000


--insert new rows
--works (log file available, dirty pages in cache)
insert into dbo.OnSecFileGroup(col1, col2)
select top (1000) row_number() over(order by (select null)), a.name
from master.dbo.spt_values as a
cross join master.dbo.spt_values as b;

--works (log file available, table read from cache)
insert into dbo.OnSecFileGroup(col1, col2)
select top (2000) col1, col2
from dbo.OnSecFileGroup;

--works
update top(500) s
set col1 = col1+100
from dbo.OnSecFileGroup as s;


--force flush to disk
--error: 
--The operating system returned error ....
--Additional messages in the SQL Server error log and system event log may provide more detail. 
--This is a severe system-level error condition that threatens database integrity and must be corrected immediately...
checkpoint;


use master
go

--db still online
select state_desc --ONLINE
from sys.databases
where name = 'mysplitdb'

--write more rows
use mysplitdb
go
--works
insert into dbo.OnSecFileGroup(col1, col2)
select top (12000) col1, col2
from dbo.OnSecFileGroup;

--error:
--Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.OnSecFileGroup'.'PK__OnSecFil__3213E83F0425A276' in database 'mysplitdb' because the 'B' filegroup is full.
--Create disk space by deleting unneeded files, dropping objects in the filegroup ...
insert into dbo.OnSecFileGroup(col1, col2)
select top (12000) col1, col2
from dbo.OnSecFileGroup;


--connection still open
--table accessible
select top (120) col1, col2
from dbo.OnSecFileGroup
order by newid();

--stop & start sql server
use master
go

--db not online
select state_desc --RECOVERY_PENDING
from sys.databases
where name = 'mysplitdb'

--stop sql server and connect usb

--start sql server

--mysplitdb online

use master
go

--db online
select state_desc --ONLINE
from sys.databases
where name = 'mysplitdb'


--remove usb
use  mysplitdb
go

--needs access to file storage, after restart, nothing in cache
select top (120) col1, col2
from dbo.OnSecFileGroup
order by newid();

--db still online

--error..
dbcc checkdb('mysplitdb')

--cleanup
drop database mysplitdb
go
```